# pandas merge timeseries, concat/append/...?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I start out with a timeseries and use a loop to produce new timeseries. I would like to merge the existing series with the new ones subsequently in every loop, while preserving their (different) indices. I tried concat, but somehow I cannot add another series after the first one...

```
orig = pd.Series(data, index=index)
for i in list:
    new = pd.Series(...)
    orig = pd.concat([orig, new], axis=1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: axis=1 can not be used here, for a series axes are not applicable. Other than that your code should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pd.concat` takes a list of Series:

```
orig = pd.concat([pd.Series(...) for i in li], axis=1)
```

(renamed your `list` to `li`)

Comment: Hi eurmiro, thanks for your quick reply! Unfortunately it is a bit more complicated than that... I am doing something with the objects from the list (regressions) and use some of the output to create the timeseries ... so I really need to append the time series after every loop...

Comment: @bigsleep - In that case your code should work. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this all the time but I use `append` like this:

```
orig = pd.Series(data, index=index)
for i in list:
    new = pd.Series(...)
    orig = orig.append(new)
```

Can you verify that the index is unique?

http://pandas.sourceforge.net/merging.html#concatenating-using-append

Can you paste the traceback? I would be happy to debug it for you.